# CSS grid centered

Tags: html, css

I try to make my site a bit more responsive.

Basically I have a `container` html element with multiple block elements inside. The block elements inside are fixed size.

What I try to achieve is that my content is always centred.

I tried something like this:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I think, I'm not the only one with this problem but I failed to name this problem or find a solution.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/k7u9e/

Comment: I dont think you need to set `margin: 0 auto;`. Just text-`align:center` would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
.images {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7u9e/1/

Comment: accept the answer to give the question an 'answered' touch? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Try this